# Using MySQL with Visual Studio (c#)

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am currently programming software to manage a MySQL database. Regularly I am a Java developer, but as far as c# is not a big deal when you are farmiliar with Java and Visual Studio greatly supports MySQL, I tried doing it this way.
I installed the official 'development kit' from MySQL to develope in Visual Basic and it is indeed very easy to connect to a database and fill a textbox with some information etc.
Lets come to my problems in detail now:

The first problem is, that I cannot find a way to draw specific fields from my database in a table. I can draw a whole table in a gridviewtable, but I only need a few fields from my database. But that is not a big deal, I might find a solution on this one.

The bigger problem is, that I cannot use the term "using MySQL;" and so I'm not able to use single SQL statements in my c# code. I installed everything properly in my opinion and can't find any problems. Even after installing everything again, I don't know why this is not working. Drag and drop things from Visual Studio works with no problems as I mentioned above.

Has someone a hint or solved the same problem already?

I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 and MySQL 5.6 (I think it is 5.6).

Thanks in advance,

Besplash

**Edit:**
It was enough to restart the PC. Im sorry.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql installer, you should see an item called Connector/NET. You need to make sure that is installed. After that is installed, right click on your project, click add reference. On the new window that opens, hit the Extensions button on the left side. Scroll down till you see `MySql.Data`. You will most likely have multiple versions of it, so mouse over them to find the right version for your .Net (it will be in the file location after `Assemblies\...`. Click hit, hit ok, then you should be able to add the `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient` to your code files.

Comment: I can use MySql.Data.MySqlClient within the code itself, but I cant use "using MySql" on top of my code to include it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are trying to place `using MySql`?

Comment: on the very top to include it. Next to using System.xyz; using System.xzy; using System.zyx;

Comment: He was simply not finding MySql. After a restart I was able to import MySql and it should work. I am going to try it now, but Visual Studio now finds MySql properly.

Comment: Alright it was enough to restart my PC. I restarted it a few times after installing MySql and everything, but somehow something didn't work until this restart now. Weird.

Answer (score 0):

Install Connector/Net and add reference to mysql.dll. There is also alternative solution - connect over ODBC. Use `OdbcConnection` class and define ODBC DSN in Control Panel connected to MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

In VS, launch the NuGet window, and do online search for MySql, and you will find needed components made by MySql AB or Oracle.